# How to assign multiple fields to an ArrayAdapter to be used with a ListView with customized ListViewItems?

Tags: java, android

I have a `ArrayList<String> taskList;` to which I add strings. Then I connect them to an `ArrayAdapter` with

```
if (mAdapter == null) {
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
                    R.layout.item_todo,
                    R.id.task_title,
                    taskList);
            mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            mAdapter.clear();
            mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

item_todo.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            ...
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvKategorie"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Kategorie" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Before, there was no

```
<TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvKategorie"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Kategorie" />
```

How do I fill not only `task_title` but also `tvKategorie` with content?

My ideas:

Create a new class `EntryCategory` to then create an `ArrayList<EntryCategory> taskList;` with fields `task_title` and `tvKategorie`.

Still the question remains how to assign `task_title` of `taskList` and `tvKategorie` of `taskList` to `mAdapter` so it shows in each item in my list?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to achieve this is by using [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

But if you still want to use ListView, I am providing one of the many solutions bellow:

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<EntryCategory>(this,
                R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title,
                taskList) {
    
    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tvTaskTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.task_title);
        TextView tvKategorie = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvKategorie);
        EntryCategory item = getItem(position);
        tvTaskTitle.setText(item.getTaskTitle());
        tvKategorie.setText(item.getKategorie());
        return view;
    }
};
```

Please excuse any syntax error as I am answering from my mobile.

---

**Update:**

Please pass `R.id.task_title` as the 3rd parameter in the `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor. So, the new code will look like the following,

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<EntryCategory>(this,
            R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title,
            taskList) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: Please share a recyclerview version for comparison

Comment: You can follow the, [FlowersAdapter](https://github.com/android/views-widgets-samples/blob/main/RecyclerViewKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/recyclersample/flowerList/FlowersAdapter.kt) which is the official sample or search for any RecyclerView tutorial.

Comment: Something is wrong about your code, getView is never called